# ODBC connection fails when running with SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I've changed an SSIS package to use a 64-bit ODBC connection instead of 32-bit.

After deployment it works fine when executing the package but when running a SQL Server Agent job with the package it fails with:

**An ODBC Error -1 has occurred**

and

**There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server**

and

**The AcquireConnection call to the connection manager Athena West-1 64-bit failed with error code 0xC0014009.**

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: [dup on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101837/odbc-connection-fails-when-running-with-sql-server-agent)

Comment: I imagine the odbc connections are registered as user ODBCs, have you configured a proxy account on SQL Server agent to run the job as the said user?

Comment: is the 64 bit driver available on the server?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a firewall is blocking the account, I'd recommend working with your security team to establish a service account in your AD, assuming this is a corporate environment

Comment: It works when running with the 32-bit version of the ODBC correction so it doesn't sound likely that it would be a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it could be SSIS package corrupted after windows or security updates. or reinstall the odbc connector to see if that works or check if SSIS/SQL libraries have been updated recently

Comment: I think this requires more explanation.